# Remove href tag along with content coldfusion

Tags: regex, coldfusion, tags, href

How can we remove `<a href` tag with full link in coldfusion?

I want to remove `"<a href="http://www.cnn.com">Harry Potter</a>"` from the below content:

```
This is some text. It is true that <a href="http://www.cnn.com">Harry Potter</a> is a good
```

I have used regular expression `"<[aA].*?>.*?</[aA]>"`

but it's not working.

Comment: <form name="acb" method="post" action="testCase.cfm">
 <textarea name="textcontet" ></textarea>
 <input type="submit" name="submit" value="submit" />
 </form>

 <cfif isdefined("form.submit")>
<cfoutput>#form.textcontet#</cfoutput><br />
<Cfset text=#form.textcontet#>
<cfset  matchData = ReReplaceNoCase(text, "<[aA][^>]*>[^<>]*<\/[aA]>", "", "all")>
<cfoutput>#matchData#</cfoutput>

Comment: what error you are getting??? and if you are getting some output what is that ??

Comment: Edit your question to add the code.  It will be more readable and you will be more likely to receive assistance.

Comment: @swetha: Comments are temporary. Please [edit] your question to include your code.

Answer (score 1):

```
<[aA][^>]*>[^<>]*<\/[aA]>
```

Try this.Replace by `empty string`.

See demo.

http://regex101.com/r/dZ1vT6/14

Comment: @swetha checked regex for coldfusion.it similar.There must be some other problem.How are you applying it

Comment: @vks This does work in cf9 at least and I can't see why it wouldn't work in earlier v's. It even picks up multiple links. Good job. `<cfset mystring = 'This is some text. It is true that <a href="http://www.cnn.com\">Harry Potter</a> is a good, but <a href="gooogle_redirect.htm">Google</a> is better'>
<cfset MyReplace = ReReplaceNoCase(mystring,"<[aA][^>]*>([^<>]*)<\/[aA]>","\1","ALL")>
<cfoutput><pre>Original string: #mystring#
Without link: #myreplace#</pre></cfoutput>` OP can replace "\1" with "" in the code if s/he likes. Good Job

Comment: @swetha His answer does work given the code sample above. Tested on cflive.net

Answer (score 1):

See [VKS answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/26377731/3917091). It should work perfectly.

--- below is my inferior answer :) ---

This should do what you want. The only trouble that you might have is any of the attributes of the link tag contains ">".

```
<cfset mystring = 'This is some text. It is true that <a href="http://www.cnn.com\">Harry Potter</a> is a good, but <a href="gooogle_redirect.htm">Google</a> is better'>
<cfset mystring2 = ReplaceNoCase(mystring,"</a>","","ALL")>
<cfset MyReplace = ReReplaceNoCase(mystring2,"<a [^>]*>","","ALL")>

<cfoutput><pre>Original string: #mystring#

Without link: #myreplace#</pre></cfoutput>
```

Alternative method: This is useful if you want to remove the link and the link's text, rather than just the link. This is a dirty workaround that I've always used. I think perhaps other languages might do this cleaner, but CF doesn't fully support regex.

Find a character, a single character, that you know isn't contained in any of your link-texts (between `<A...>` and `</A>`). I chose ~, but you may need to find another. Set "closer" to that character.

```
<cfset closer="~">
<cfset mystring = 'This is some text. It is true that <a href="http://www.cnn.com\">Harry Potter</a> is a good, but <a href="gooogle_redirect.htm">Google</a> is better'>
<cfset mystring2 = ReplaceNoCase(mystring,"</a>","#closer#","ALL")>
<cfset MyReplace = ReReplaceNoCase(mystring2,"<a [^>]*>([^#closer#]*)#closer#","","ALL")>

<cfoutput><pre>Original string: #mystring#

Without link: #myreplace#</pre></cfoutput>
```

This will replace

> This is some text. It is true that [Harry Potter](http://www.cnn.com) is a good, but [Google](/gooogle_redirect.htm) is better

with

> This is some text. It is true that  is a good, but  is better

If you want it to remove the entire link and text, just take out the \1 from the ReReplaceNoCase above.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you want to keep the text that is between the hyperlink:

```
<cfsavecontent variable="content">
   This is some text. It is true that <a href="http://www.cnn.com">Harry Potter</a> is a good
</cfsavecontent>

<cfset content = reReplaceNoCase(content, "(<a.*?>)(.*?)(</a>)", "\2", "all") />
<cfoutput>#content#</cfoutput>
```

would result in:

> This is some text. It is true that Harry Potter is a good